# C++ program cannot exit even with return 0 as the first line in main

Tags: c++

I've written a simple http server based socket.
But it cannot exit by `return 0;` in the main function even in this way:

```
int main(int argc, wchar_t* argv[])
{
    return 0;
}
```

The program will be blocked at `(*function_to_call)();` in `doexit(code, 0, 0);`.
When I directly close the cmd window, there is an alert:

> (ntdll.dll) send invalid parameters to service or function

I doubt that there is something wrong with my projects config. But I was not able to find the reason.

Comment: Guess: you have some global objects and their dtor is causing problems.

Comment: My psychic powers tell me that you got an instance of a c++ class as a global variable or static member somewhere.  It's destructor is doing something weird after main returns.  (btw, this is exactly why I discourage people on my team from using global instances.)

Comment: _“The program will be blocked at”_ …some code that you have not included in the question! Just reminding of our magic formula: [mcve]

Comment: @selbie as you said,it's caused by some object,but not static member,that is the logger object of log4cplus,I use it as a public variable in a singleton class,its really strange that I didn't use it as static member variable and use this singleton class in anywhere,but it still cause this problem...

Comment: log4cplus::initialize() must be the first line in my 'main()',this is important on windows platform,and this is why my program cannot stop!Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4):

A simple case to simulate this is:

```
struct A{ ~A() { while(true); } };
A a;

int main() {}
```

The `a` destructor function is called when `main` has finished. But this function block for some reason so the program is blocked.